# java Catch exception inside a async callback

Tags: java, asynchronous, exception, callback

I have a callback which may throw a custom exception.
I'm trying to throw it, but it's not being catched on the outer scope, nor the compiler let me catch it, it says: "Exception is never thrown is the corresponding try block", even though it is.

this is my code:

```
public void openAsync(MessageAsyncCallback callback) {
        try {
            this.sendChannelOpen(this.getChannel(), getChannelOpenData().getFlags(), new MessageAsyncCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete() throws NanoException {
//                INanoPacket message = transport.getMessageByClassName(AudioServerHandshake.class.getName());
                    INanoPacket message = transport.getMessageByClassName(AudioClientHandshake.class.getName());
                    Log.info("Got audio server handshake, trying to client-handshake it");
                    sendClientHandshakeAsync((AudioServerHandshake) message, callback);
                }
            });
        } catch (NanoException e) {
            System.exit(-2);
        }
    }
```

and it doesn't let me catch `NanoException`

**EDIT:**
inside `transport.getMessageByClassName` I throw a `NanoException`.

**EDIT2:**
this is the method who invokes the exception:

```
public INanoPacket getMessageByClassName(String destClassName) throws NanoException {//} throws NanoException {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); // fetch starting time
        INanoPacket message = this.getMessageFromTCPQueue();

        while (!(message.getClass().getName().equals(destClassName)) && isRuntimeValid(startTime)) {
            this.insertToTCPQueue(message); // put message back in queue
            message = this.getMessageFromTCPQueue();
        }

        if (!(message.getClass().getName().equals(destClassName))) {
            // timeout...
            throw new NanoException("Couldn't find destination message: " + destClassName);
        }

        return message;
    }
```

and I want to handle the exception not even in `openAsync` but on the method that calls `openAsync`.
**why?** because I'm handling messages coming from a remote device, this is why it's async. and I'm using some kind of timeout to wait for a specific message, and if the message isn't coming I want to restart the whole program.

Comment: You can't catch the exception here because you are running this asynchronously. Normally, in the AsyncCallback, there's a field or a method or class to get/handle an error message if an exception happens

Comment: @ControlAltDel can you please provide an example on how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please notice that in your code you are not invoking `onComplete` method, you are defining it.

The exception would be thrown in a separate part of the code, possibly separate `Thread` (as it seems to be async). Therefore the "Exception is never thrown is the corresponding try block" message is right, as the exception will never be thrown when invoking `this.sendChannelOpen(...)` method.

Your `try-catch` statement needs to wrap the place where you invoke the `onComplete` method. As only by invoking `onComplete` method can you expect `NanoException`.

EDIT based on comments:
If you need to handle the exception throw in `getMessageByClassName` you can do it in `onComplete` method and not rethrow it. If you want to handle it somewhere else, you'd need to provide us the code of `sendChannelOpen` method or a place where the callback is invoked.

EDIT2 (based on question edits):
Please see the code below, as an example of how you can communicate between threads. I've used Latch, but there are other classes in java.util.concurrent that you may find useful.
BTW, I'm not going into the discussion why you want to restart the whole app on your NanoException, although there might be other options worth considering for recovering from that Exception.

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

class NanoException extends Exception {}

interface MessageAsyncCallback {
    void onComplete() throws NanoException;
}

public class AsyncApp {
    private static final CountDownLatch errorLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AsyncApp().run();
    }

    void run() {
        sendChannelOpen("something", new MessageAsyncCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete() throws NanoException {
                // the whole try-catch-sleep is not really needed, just to wait a bit before exception is thrown
                try {
                    // not needed, just to wait a bit before exception is thrown
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new NanoException();
                }
                throw new NanoException();
            }
        });

        try {
            System.out.println("This is a main thread and we wait here, while the other thread executes...");
            errorLatch.await();
            System.out.println("Latch has reached 0, will now exit.");
            System.exit(-2);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in main thread.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }

    void sendChannelOpen(String notImportant, MessageAsyncCallback troublesomeCallback) {
        runSomethingInSeparateThread(troublesomeCallback);
    }

    void runSomethingInSeparateThread(MessageAsyncCallback troublesomeCallback) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                troublesomeCallback.onComplete();
            } catch (NanoException e) {
                System.out.println("You can catch it here, and do system exit here or synchronize with main Thread as below");
                errorLatch.countDown();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I know. inside the `onComplete` I run `transport.getMessageByClassName` which over there I throw by default an exception that I a, trying to catch, and I want to handle it in the class who calls this method.

Comment: So you either need to catch the exception inside the onComplete method - will update my answer in a moment, or update your question with how `sendChannelOpen`  method looks like.

Comment: @Finer essentially it sounds like you'd like to de-async this process, correct?

Comment: Hi, I've edited my question and added a bit more details on my use case. it's must be async, but I need to wait for a specific message, and if I don't get it, I want to restart it.

Comment: Thank you for adding more info to the question. So what you want to achieve cannot be done using Exceptions, as Exception is tightly connected to the Thread it was raised in. You’d need a way to synchronize the main thread with the thread that handles messages - this can be done in various ways - i.e using a Latch. I can provide an example a bit later. Anyway, if you want to throw and handle the Exception somewhere (to later synchronize threads) you need to do this where onComplete is invoked. The details of getMessageByClassName are not needed.

Comment: @Finer - I've updated my answer with an example of how you could synchronize between threads. Hope that helps - without info about how `sendChannelOpen` handles the callback and how the callback is invoked, I'm not able to suggest anything else.

Comment: thank you. I will use countdownLatch to workaround with it.
is it a bad thing to use it? is it not efficient?

Comment: using CountdownLatch is not a bad thing if you need to synchronize between threads. There is also a Semaphore class that you may find useful. Those are provided by core java lib and as such should be very safe to use and provide good performance.